# Django: How to clean a model with inlines?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I created an app that implements a quiz. I got a glitch, however, when I tried to clean a model.

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
def clean(self):
        options = Option.objects.filter(question=self)
        correct = 0
        for option in options:
            option.save()
            print(option)
            if option.correct == True:
                correct += 1
                print(correct)
        if correct > 1:
            raise ValidationError(_('Please only input 1 correct answer.'))
        if correct <= 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('Please input 1 correct answer.'))

        #limit questions
        if options.count() > 4:
            raise ValidationError(_('Only 4 maximum amount of options!'))

class Option(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="question")
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Correct?")
```

The problem I figured is that when the site tries to save each question, it saves each model **Question** before saving each **Option**.

Is there a way to get past this?

Comment: That makes sence, since Django *first* need to create a `Question`, before it can create `Option`s. This is necessary since the `ForeignKey` needs to know the primary key of the question to which it is linked.

Comment: You probably should do the validation in the `Option`s object, but still it is possible to circumvent this for example with create/update/delete operations in bulk.